# EF Code first invalid column name "CategoryCategoryID"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

There is a existing database named Northwind with a webform application.
when running the application raise up a error:
'invalid column name CategoryCategoryID'.
any one help me?.
thanks in advance!!

**Category.cs:**

```
public class Category
{

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   // public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs:**

```
public class Product
{

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    //public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued{ get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category{ get; set; }
}
```

**Northwind.cs**

```
public class Northwind:   DbContext
{
    public DbSet< Product  > Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet< Category > Categorys{ get; set; }
}
```

**Products.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Northwind northwind = new Northwind();

    var products = from p in northwind.Products
    where p.Discontinued == false
    select p;

    GridView1.DataSource = products.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: why you commented Id? probably schema mis match

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add a new FK property to your `Product` entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }        
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ForeignKey is in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; namespace and can also be put on the [ForeignKey("Category")]

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

Comment: How about making it optional?

Comment: @Morteza Manani how could this be done if we only had the navigation property in the Products class, using FluentAPI?