# C# code-first EF 6. Invalid Column Name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I try to get data from the table `Anexos`, I get this Exeption:

> "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."
>
> "Invalid column name 'Empresas_Id'."

Then I was looking for the `Empresas_Id` field in my model. But..

```
public class Anexos
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição"), StringLength(150)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [StringLength(90)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Caminho { get; set; }

    [Column("PessoaId")]
    public int? PessoaId { get; set; }

    [Column("Contrato_Id")]
    public int? ContratoId { get; set; }

    [Column("TipoDocumento_Id")]
    public int TipoDocumentoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContratoId")]
    public virtual Contratos Contrato { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PessoaId")]
    public virtual Pessoas Pessoa { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TipoDocumentoId")]
    public virtual TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }

}
```

There is no `Empresas_Id` field, then I checked my database table, but nothing there too... The `Contratos` model have the field, but I can take the data from it without errors. Is this a bug of EF ?

I checked this answers trying to find my issue:

- [entity framework 4.1 invalid column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055962/entity-framework-4-1-invalid-column-name)
- [EF Code First “Invalid column name 'Discriminator'” but no inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553935/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-discriminator-but-no-inheritance)
- [Entity Framework - Invalid Column Name '*_ID"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959256/entity-framework-invalid-column-name-id)
- [EF Code first invalid column name “CategoryCategoryID”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058068/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name-categorycategoryid)

  PS: All of my migrations are up-to-date.

### Edit

My table Script :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Anexos] (
    [Id]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao]        NVARCHAR (150) NULL,
    [Nome]             NVARCHAR (90)  NULL,
    [Caminho]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PessoaId]         INT            NULL,
    [Contrato_Id]      INT            NULL,
    [TipoDocumento_Id] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Anexos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Anexos_dbo.Contratos_Contrato_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Contrato_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Contratos] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Anexos_dbo.Pessoas_PessoaId] FOREIGN KEY ([PessoaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Pessoas] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Anexos_dbo.TipoDocumento_TipoDocumento_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([TipoDocumento_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TipoDocumento] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PessoaId]
    ON [dbo].[Anexos]([PessoaId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Contrato_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Anexos]([Contrato_Id] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TipoDocumento_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Anexos]([TipoDocumento_Id] ASC);
```

My connection string :

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=PC-TREINA09\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=erp10_new;integrated security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

### Edit 2 :

The `Contratos` table:

```
public class Contratos
{
    public Contratos()
    {
        Items = new HashSet<ContratoItens>();
        Anexos = new HashSet<Anexos>();
        Contas = new HashSet<ContasContasReceber>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataContrato { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataVenda { get; set; }

    public int? DiaDoMesCobranca { get; set; }

    public int? MesesVigencia { get; set; }

    public string Observacoes { get; set; }

    public TipoDesconto? TipoDesconto { get; set; }

    public double? ValorDesconto { get; set; }

    public double? ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public StatusContrato Status { get; set; }

    [Column("EmpresaId")]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    [Column("Cliente_Id")]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Column("ClienteFaturamento_Id")]
    public int ClienteFaturamentoId { get; set; }

    [Column("Pagamento_Id")]
    public int? PagamentoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
    public virtual Empresas Empresa { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual PessoasCliente Cliente { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteFaturamentoId")]
    public virtual PessoasCliente ClienteFaturamento { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PagamentoId")]
    public virtual Pagamentos Pagamento { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Anexos> Anexos { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContratoItens> Items { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContasContasReceber> Contas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possibly you could have added the column after adding the table to EF, can you please remove the table from EF and Add it again

Comment: May be your context connection string is different than your db, can you share table script and connection string in app.config or web.config

Comment: @VickyS I already did this. : (

Comment: You need to check the Contratos table.  If that column is not suppose to be there then you need to delete it from the model and re-add the table to the model.  The Contratos is a child table of the Anexos model why you won't see it in the Anexox table.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev edited

Comment: @developer_117 `Anexos` is a dependent of `Contratos`.

Comment: Is that 'Empresas_Id' column exists in relational table classes?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev it exists in `Contratos`, but it's `EmpresaId` and not `Empresas_Id`  in that table.

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee have you checked the reference in the data model? Typically in the model if you look at the Anexox table, there might be a reference back to the Contratos table.  Try deleting that reference.

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee In 'Contratos' table column name is 'EmpresaId', but in 'Contratos.cs' column name is 'Empresa_Id', am I right?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev in the model and in table they are the same

Comment: @developer_117 i delete the relationship, migrated, updated, recreated, migrated, updated and... the same error ;-;

Comment: Any chance to have something like `public ICollection<Anexos> Anexos { get; set; }` in your `Empresas` class?

Comment: @IvanStoev no, not found, by the way see the answer/answer inner question.

Comment: I saw it, but don't think it's a solution - `AsEnumerable` simply defers the execution of the query for later time, while `ToList` executes it immediately. There must be something else in the code not shown here which is causing it. Any class inheriting `Anexos`? Can you mark `Anexos` and `Empresas` as `sealed`?

Comment: @developer_117 I answred it, any idea for the inner question?

Comment: @IvanStoev `Anexos` doesn't inherit and no one inherit `Anexos`, yes I can mark as sealed, they are not parent of any class.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev  answred it, any idea for the inner question?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee Can you show us the Contratos table as well?

Comment: @developer_117 there it is.

Comment: @developer_117 found it, see the edit

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev found it, see the edit

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know why but, when a send to my GridView as a `List<T>` model it gives me that error, but if I send using `AsEnumarable` instead of `ToList`, it works:

```
public ActionResult IndexContratos(int id)
{
     var anexos = db.Anexos
        .Include(a => a.Contrato)
        .Include(a => a.Pessoa)
        .Include(a => a.TipoDocumento)
        .Where(x => x.ContratoId == id);

      AnexosContratoTemps(id);

      return View("Grid", anexos.AsEnumerable());//Works !!
      //return View("Grid", anexos.ToList()); //Invalid column name...
}
```

My View model is:

```
@model IEnumerable<Anexos>
```

But a `List<T>` is a `IEnumarable<T>`, I really don't understand that why `ToList` gives me that error, can someone explain?

### Edit

Finally(by coincidence) I found what was that bug, I forgot to say that the `Anexos` property in `MyContext` class was virtual, something like this:

```
public DbSet<Anexos> Anexos { get; set; } //WRONG!
public virtual DbSet<Anexos> Anexos { get; set; }//YAYYY!!
```

Comment: I think it will just give you the error in a different place (when enumerating inside the view).